# Access SQL syntax error when using OleDbCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am going to INSERT data in Access Database using OleDbDataAdapter in C# but i got an error with message **Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Command**

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\\PMS.mdb");
worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.DoWork += InsertJob;
worker.ProgressChanged += InsertJobCompleted;
worker.RunWorkerAsync(args);
```

And InsertJob Function is:

```
private void InsertJob(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     var args = (InsertJobArgs)e.Argument;
     try
        {
            dbAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Sheet", dbConnection);                
            dbAdapter.Fill(args.DataTable);
            var builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dbAdapter);
            var row = args.DataTable.NewRow();

            row["UserName"] = args.Entry.UserName;
            row["Password"] = args.Entry.Password;
            args.DataTable.Rows.Add(row);

            dbAdapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();               
            dbAdapter.Update(args.DataTable);
            builder.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            args.Exception = ex;
            worker.ReportProgress(0, args);
            return;
        }
        worker.ReportProgress(100, args);
}
```

I recieve Error on line : `dbAdapter.Update(args.DataTable);`

I tried to debug it with visual studio and found that All the InsertCommand Parameters Values are `null`

And I tried to insert it manually by this code before call to `dbAdapter.Update(args.DataTable);`

```
dbAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = args.Entry.UserName;
dbAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters[1].Value = args.Entry.Password;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

Immediately after the line

```
var builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dbAdapter);
```

add the two lines

```
builder.QuotePrefix = "[";
builder.QuoteSuffix = "]";
```

That will tell the `OleDbCommandBuilder` to wrap table and column names in square brackets, producing an INSERT command like

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] ...
```

instead of the default form

```
INSERT INTO TableName ...
```

The square brackets are required if any table or column names contain spaces or "funny" characters, or if they happen to be reserved words in Access SQL. (In your case, I suspect that your table has a column named [Password], and `PASSWORD` is a reserved word in Access SQL.)