# "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" and "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

So I'm doing my first computing project using Visual Basic 2010 which connects to an Access 2010 database, and I've been getting two different error codes in my project that I can't seem to get my head around:

1. In the code for my button that allows the user to update information, I get the error message

   > No value given for one or more required parameters.

   when I click the button while it is debugging.

Here's the code for the button:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim cbMember As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daMember)   'returns items from text box to dataset
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(0) = txtMemberID.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(1) = txtForename.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(2) = txtSurname.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(3) = txtDOB.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(4) = txtSex.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(5) = txtPhone.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(6) = txtEmail.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(7) = txtAddress.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(8) = txtPostcode.Text
    daMember.Update(dsMember, "Members") 'updates items to database
    MsgBox("Data updated")`
```

the line of code that I get the error message for is the `daMember.Update(dsMember, "Members")` line. How can I get this to work, because I feel like I've tried everything.

2. In the code for my button that adds a new record to the database, I get an error message

   > Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

   when I click the button while it is debugging, and once again I have no idea how to fix it. I get the error message when I click the button.

Here's the code for the button:

```
Private Sub btnCommit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click

    If MemberRowNumber <> -1 Then 'checks for a valid record to add
        Dim cbMember As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daMember)   'declare new variables specifically for this statement
        Dim dsMemberNewRow As DataRow
        dsMemberNewRow = dsMember.Tables("Members").NewRow() 'adds new row
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("MemberID") = txtMemberID.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Forename") = txtForename.Text    'contains values to add to new row
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Surname") = txtSurname.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("DOB") = txtDOB.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Sex") = txtSex.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Phone_Number") = txtPhone.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("E-Mail_Address") = txtEmail.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Home_Address") = txtAddress.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Postcode") = txtPostcode.Text
        dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows.Add(dsMemberNewRow)  'creates new object
        daMember.Update(dsMember, "Members")
        MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")  'display message once process is completed

    End If

End Sub
```

The line of code that the error message seems to relate to is once again the `daMember.Update(dsMember, "Members")` line. Please help, because it's making me tear my hair out in frustration!

Also, I apologise if this was worded badly since this is the first time I've posted on this website, so thanks for your patience. Thank you in advance!

Here's the full code, if it helps:

```
Public Class member_details

Dim ParkwoodConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection      'this variable will now hold the control object
Dim Provider As String
Dim dbSource As String
Dim dsMember As New DataSet    'set up DataSet for members table
Dim daMember As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter     'set up DataAdapter for members table
Dim dsRunning As New DataSet    'set up DataSet for Running table
Dim daRunning As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter     'set up DataAdapter for Running table
Dim dsCycling As New DataSet    'set up DataSet for Cycling table
Dim daCycling As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter     'set up DataAdapter for Cycling table
Dim dsSwimming As New DataSet    'set up DataSet for Swimming table
Dim daSwimming As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter     'set up DataAdapter for Swimming table
Dim sqlMemberQuery As String
Dim sqlRunningQuery As String
Dim sqlCyclingQuery As String
Dim sqlSwimmingQuery As String
Dim MemberRowNumber As Integer
Dim MemberNumberOfRows As Integer
Dim dtRunning As New DataTable
Dim dtCycling As New DataTable
Dim dtSwimming As New DataTable

Private Sub AccessProject1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Provider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"         'technology used to conntect to database
    dbSource = "Data Source = training_log.accdb"           'pathname for database

    ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource        'establish connection between form and database

    ParkwoodConnection.Open()        'open database
    sqlMemberQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblMembers"       'select all records from database
    daMember = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlMemberQuery, ParkwoodConnection)     'pass object to daMember variable
    daMember.Fill(dsMember, "Members")       'fills dataset with records from table

    ParkwoodConnection.Close()       'close database

    MemberNumberOfRows = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows.Count      'get how many rows are in tblMembers
    MemberRowNumber = 0   'set the intial row number to 0 when the form opens
    DisplayData()   'display the data on to the form

    Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
    dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
    ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
    ParkwoodConnection.Open()
    sqlRunningQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblRunning WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text  'Use sql to get the data from the database table
    daRunning = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlRunningQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
    dtRunning.Clear()
    daRunning.Fill(dtRunning)
    grdRunResults.DataSource = dtRunning   'Populate the datagrid

    ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

    Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
    dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
    ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
    ParkwoodConnection.Open()
    sqlSwimmingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblSwimming WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
    daSwimming = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSwimmingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
    dtSwimming.Clear()
    daSwimming.Fill(dtSwimming)
    grdSwimResults.DataSource = dtSwimming   'Populate the datagrid

    ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

    Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
    dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
    ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
    ParkwoodConnection.Open()
    sqlCyclingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblCycling WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
    daCycling = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCyclingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
    dtCycling.Clear()
    daCycling.Fill(dtCycling)
    grdCycleResults.DataSource = dtCycling   'Populate the datagrid

    ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

End Sub

Private Sub DisplayData()

    txtMemberID.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(0) 'displays the members' ID in a text box
    txtForename.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(1) 'displays the members' forename in a text box
    txtSurname.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(2) 'displays the members' surname in a text box
    txtDOB.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(3)    'displays the members' date of birth in a text box
    txtSex.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(4)   'displays the members' sex
    txtPhone.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(5)    'displays the members' phone number in a text box
    txtEmail.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(6)  'displays the members' Emails in a text box
    txtAddress.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(7)    'displays the members' address in a text box
    txtPostcode.Text = dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(8)   'displays the members' postcode in a text box

End Sub
Private Sub btnNextRecord_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNextRecord.Click

    If MemberRowNumber <> MemberNumberOfRows - 1 Then   'moves forward to next row
        MemberRowNumber = MemberRowNumber + 1
        DisplayData()

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlRunningQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblRunning WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text  'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daRunning = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlRunningQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtRunning.Clear()
        daRunning.Fill(dtRunning)
        grdRunResults.DataSource = dtRunning   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlSwimmingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblSwimming WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daSwimming = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSwimmingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtSwimming.Clear()
        daSwimming.Fill(dtSwimming)
        grdSwimResults.DataSource = dtSwimming   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlCyclingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblCycling WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daCycling = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCyclingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtCycling.Clear()
        daCycling.Fill(dtCycling)
        grdCycleResults.DataSource = dtCycling   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

    Else
        MsgBox("No More Rows")      'display message when last row is reached
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnPreviousRecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPreviousRecord.Click

    If MemberRowNumber > 0 Then   'moves to previous row
        MemberRowNumber = MemberRowNumber - 1
        DisplayData()
        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlRunningQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblRunning WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daRunning = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlRunningQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtRunning.Clear()
        daRunning.Fill(dtRunning)
        grdRunResults.DataSource = dtRunning  'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlSwimmingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblSwimming WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daSwimming = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSwimmingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtSwimming.Clear()
        daSwimming.Fill(dtSwimming)
        grdSwimResults.DataSource = dtSwimming   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlCyclingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblCycling WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daCycling = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCyclingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtCycling.Clear()
        daCycling.Fill(dtCycling)
        grdCycleResults.DataSource = dtCycling   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

    Else
        MsgBox("First Record")  'displays message if first row is reached
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnLastRecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLastRecord.Click

    If MemberRowNumber <> MemberNumberOfRows - 1 Then   'moves to last record
        MemberRowNumber = MemberNumberOfRows - 1
        DisplayData()
        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlRunningQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblRunning WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daRunning = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlRunningQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtRunning.Clear()
        daRunning.Fill(dtRunning)
        grdRunResults.DataSource = dtRunning   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlSwimmingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblSwimming WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daSwimming = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSwimmingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtSwimming.Clear()
        daSwimming.Fill(dtSwimming)
        grdSwimResults.DataSource = dtSwimming   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlCyclingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblCycling WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daCycling = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCyclingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtCycling.Clear()
        daCycling.Fill(dtCycling)
        grdCycleResults.DataSource = dtCycling  'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnFirstRecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFirstRecord.Click

    If MemberRowNumber <> 0 Then  'moves to first record
        MemberRowNumber = 0
        DisplayData()
        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlRunningQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblRunning WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daRunning = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlRunningQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtRunning.Clear()
        daRunning.Fill(dtRunning)
        grdRunResults.DataSource = dtRunning   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlSwimmingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblSwimming WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daSwimming = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSwimmingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtSwimming.Clear()
        daSwimming.Fill(dtSwimming)
        grdSwimResults.DataSource = dtSwimming   'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

        Provider = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"   'Set up link to the database
        dbSource = "Data Source = Training_Log.accdb"
        ParkwoodConnection.ConnectionString = Provider & dbSource    'Open the database
        ParkwoodConnection.Open()
        sqlCyclingQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblCycling WHERE MemberID =" & txtMemberID.Text   'Use sql to get the data from the database table
        daCycling = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCyclingQuery, ParkwoodConnection) 'Set up data adapter
        dtCycling.Clear()
        daCycling.Fill(dtCycling)
        grdCycleResults.DataSource = dtCycling  'Populate the datagrid

        ParkwoodConnection.Close()   'Close the connection

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim cbMember As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daMember)   'returns items from text box to dataset
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(0) = txtMemberID.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(1) = txtForename.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(2) = txtSurname.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(3) = txtDOB.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(4) = txtSex.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(5) = txtPhone.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(6) = txtEmail.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(7) = txtAddress.Text
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Item(8) = txtPostcode.Text
    daMember.Update(dsMember, "Members") 'updates items to database
    MsgBox("Data updated")

End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click

    txtMemberID.Clear()
    txtForename.Clear()    'clears the forename text box
    txtSurname.Clear()     'clears the surname text box
    txtDOB.Clear()     'clears the Date of Birth text box
    txtSex.Clear()     'clears the sex text box
    txtPhone.Clear()    'clears the phone number text box
    txtEmail.Clear()    'clears the email text box
    txtAddress.Clear()     'clears the Address text box
    txtPostcode.Clear()     'clears the postcode text box

    dtRunning.Clear()   'clears the running results table
    dtCycling.Clear()   'clears the cycling results table
    dtSwimming.Clear()  'clears the swimming results table

End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

    MemberRowNumber = 0   'clears fields
    DisplayData()

End Sub

Private Sub btnCommit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click

    If MemberRowNumber <> -1 Then 'checks for a valid record to add
        Dim cbMember As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daMember)   'declare new variables specifically for this statement
        Dim dsMemberNewRow As DataRow
        dsMemberNewRow = dsMember.Tables("Members").NewRow() 'adds new row
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("MemberID") = txtMemberID.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Forename") = txtForename.Text    'contains values to add to new row
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Surname") = txtSurname.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("DOB") = txtDOB.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Sex") = txtSex.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Phone_Number") = txtPhone.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("E-Mail_Address") = txtEmail.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Home_Address") = txtAddress.Text
        dsMemberNewRow.Item("Postcode") = txtPostcode.Text
        dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows.Add(dsMemberNewRow)  'creates new object
        daMember.Update(dsMember, "Members")
        MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")  'display message once process is completed

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Delete this Record?", _
                       "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        MsgBox("Operation Cancelled")   'display message if record is not deleted
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim cbMember As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daMember)
    dsMember.Tables("Members").Rows(MemberRowNumber).Delete()   'selects row to delete
    MemberNumberOfRows = MemberNumberOfRows - 1 'reduce number of rows
    MemberRowNumber = 0   'display first record
    DisplayData()
    daMember.Update(dsMember, "Members") 'updates database

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It's saying you have more columns in the table in the db, than you are setting in the code or that one of the ones you have in the code is null and you've made it not null in the table. Can't see it from here, but that's what you should be looking for.

Comment: Try the suggestion in the related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19557920/2144390) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this problem many times. SQL query's the problem. That's why the message shows is because the SQL parser cannot identify a token in your SQL query and interprets it as a parameter for WHICH you must or need to provide a value.

Give values. Count your DB's columns, then count how many values you have. Then, give a parameter of it and MAKE sure you didn't miss one of it.