# Add Variables To Access Database In A Loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, for-loop, ms-access

Currently, I want to add a list into an Access Database. However, I'm not sure how to.
This is my current code:

```python
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\eesam\OneDrive\Documents\Eesa\Home\Coding\Hacking\Brute Force Attacks\Database.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

passes = ["1", "69", "hello", "saw", "hiaf", "oln", "oi"]

for i in passes:
    print(i)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PASS (PASSWORD)" +
                    f"VALUES({i})")

    conn.commit()
```

Each Time I try, I get the error "pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')"

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You missed a space before _VALUES_ and you should put `{i}` in quotes.

Comment: you can use `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PASS (PASSWORD) VALUES (?)", (i,))`. This will prevent you of having to add quotes around the `i` variable.

Comment: Also, `PASSWORD` is a reserved word in Access SQL so you'll need to enclose the column name in square brackets: `INSERT INTO PASS ([PASSWORD]) VALUES (?)`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19557920/2144390